# How to get the value present in inner html of the td tag in table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, jsdom, html-tableextract

index.html

```
   <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<%=rn%>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<%=na%>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<%=pe%>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="nbed" id="nbed" value="<%=ad%>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="obed" id="obed" value="<%=obed%>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="ibed" id="ibed" value="<%=ibed%>">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="edit">
                <button type="button" onclick="loadAjax()">edit</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="sid" value = "<%=rn%>" id="sid">
                <button type="button" onclick="loadAjax2()">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </form>
       <% } %>
       </tr>
```

script.js

```
var table = document.getElementById("data");

            for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
            {
                for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                        console.log(col.innerHTML);
                }  
            }
```

When I iterate this table I get the html part of each td tag like this,

```
        **<input type="text" name="location" id="location" value=" fkeaqwji" pwa2-uuid="EDITOR/input-478-395-B6990-D43" pwa-fake-editor="">**
```

How shall I get the value present in the value tag of this Inner html?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `col.querySelector('input').value` ?

Comment: It throws an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Comment: for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
   {
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
         console.log(col.querySelector('input').value);
       }  
   }

Comment: I was giving for granted that your code was working as far as printing out the innerHTML. If that thing works, it means that the col object is !== null. After that considering that in your html every single td contains an input, col.querySelector('input') should never be null. Anyway I shared a demo in my answer just to repeat the same thing and show the evidence.

Comment: col.querySelector('input')  returns the innerhtml but when I access the value... it says null

Comment: because you are using a different html than what you stated in your question. As you can see the demo works just fine as expected. Anyway I just added in my demo a condition checking if there's any input element before trying to access its value and show it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the value of `<input>` elements nested inside the table cells, using `col.querySelector('input').value`.

I crafted this demo on top of your code:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("data");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
{
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    const inputElement = col.querySelector('input');
    //just in case there's no input element inside the td
    if (inputElement !== null){
       const value = inputElement.value;
       console.log( value );
    }        
  }  
}
```

```css
tr{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<table id="data">
   <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<%=rn%>">
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<%=na%>">
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<%=pe%>">
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" name="nbed" id="nbed" value="<%=ad%>">
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" name="obed" id="obed" value="<%=obed%>">
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" name="ibed" id="ibed" value="<%=ibed%>">
      </td>    
   </tr>
</table>
```